# how to open a modal (bootstrap) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="loader">  
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:240px;">
                      <div class="modal-body">     
                          <input  type="range" id="loaderd"   min="-50" max="0">
                      </div>     
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

and JQuery

```
$('#loader').modal('show');
```

The error coming is

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function  @ ssss.js:546onclick @ ssss.htm:1
```

What's the problem?
And is working with a button like this

```
<img id="volumeClickedMiniPlayer" src="img/volume.png"  width="25px" height="25px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loader">
```

Comment: ids are different.Missed "r" in html

Comment: "$(...).modal is not a function" Will occur when the library is not added properly. Please check if the library is added properly.

Comment: @Raviteja i think it is just a trypo error

Comment: no no its not type error... I've done it here, originally its good... Please help ... Libraries are also added and working when button is used for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Checout out some of the points ..**

> **1.** First check if you have added the bootstrap library.
>
> **2.** if added , than check if you have   **include jQuery before** including bootstrap's javascript.**Since bootstrap actually needs jQuery.**
>
> **3.** Check if you included library more than Once

*For example*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

*and do this:*

```
$(window).load(function() {

jQuery.noConflict();
    $('#loader').modal('show');
});
```

**If it does not work even now.. than remove your jquery and and bootstrap library and use *bootstrap 3.3.5 and jquery 1.11.3*.**

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap css plugin:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal" id="loader">  
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:240px;">
                  <div class="modal-body">     
                      <input  type="range" id="loaderd"   min="-50" max="0">
                  </div>     
              </div>
          </div>
```

Plugin:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loader').modal('show');
});

</script>
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

If you have added all external files correctly then,
You need to remove `hide` class

```
<div id="loader" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:240px;">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="range" id="loaderd" min="-50" max="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#loader').modal('show');
```

[**With Hide Class demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/b3qf8w6v/1/)

[**Without hide class demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/b3qf8w6v/)